# PHP - Download script only downloads 300B instead of 170MB

Tags: php, download

I'm having an issue when trying to make a download script on my website. What ends up happening is that it only downloads between 160B to 310B instead of the whole 170MB that the file is. I'm not sure why it's happening, and if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated. Also, I'm not sure if it's an issue with the code itself or that my host doesn't allow big files to be downloaded, as I get this message on net2ftp: "Files which are too big can't be downloaded, uploaded, copied, moved, searched, zipped, unzipped, viewed or edited; they can only be renamed, chmodded or deleted."

Here is my code:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

$path = "/versions/";
$dl_file = $_GET['file'];
$fullPath = $path.$dl_file;

if ($fd = fopen($fullPath, "r")) {
  $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
  $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);

  header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
  header("Content-length: $fsize");
  header("Cache-control: private");
  while(!feof($fd)) {
    $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
    echo $buffer;
  }
}
fclose($fd);
exit;
```

Comment: Have you verified all of your variable values?

Comment: And is path correct? That looks like an absolute path. If the file is relative to the script location, prefix the path with `__DIR__`

Comment: The php file is in the public_html directory. Inside that is the versions folder, which holds the zip file

Comment: See my second comment. :)

Comment: Hi sorry didnt notice that. Any chancellor could teach me how __DIR__ works and where in the variable I'd put it? I'm new to php so it's not familiar.

Comment: Try `$path = __DIR__ . "/versions/";`